# Is there a way to check for available microphones using pyaudio?

Tags: python, microphone, pyaudio, input-devices

I was looking through PyAudio documentation and i found these two methods:

```
1: info.get('deviceCount')
2: p.get_default_input_device_info()
```

Which returns:

```
output 1: 3
output 2: IOError
```

My pc currently has no microphones plugged but has 3 speakers.

Is there a way to check for available microphones returning a zero instead of an IO error with pyaudio?

Answer (score 0):

I got it by doing this:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
try:
    print(p.get_default_input_device_info())
except:
    print("No mics availiable")
```

`output: No mics availiable`